# how go get RGB values of ROI selected in depth stream

Tags: c++, kinect

I wrote an simple kinect application where I'm accessing the depth values to detect some objects. I use the following code to get the depth value

```
depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(pBufferRun);
```

this will give me the depth value for each pixel. Now I want to subselect a region of the image, and get the RGB camera values of this corresponding region.

What I'm not sure about:

- do I need to open a color image stream?
- or is it enough to just convert the depth into color?
- how do I use `NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinateFrameFromDepthPixelFrameAtResolution`?

I'm fine with the simplest solution where I have a depth frame and a color frame, so that I can select a ROI with opencv and then crop the color frame accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- do I need to open a color image stream?

Yes. You can get the coordinates in the colour frame without opening the stream, but you won't be able to do anything useful with them because you'll have no colour data to index into!

- or is it enough to just convert the depth into color?

There's no meaningful conversion of distance into colour. You need two image streams, and a co-ordinate conversion function.

- how do I use NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinateFrameFromDepthPixelFrameAtResolution?

That's a terribly documented function. Go take a look at [NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663857.aspx) instead, because the function arguments and documentation actually make sense! Depth value and depth (x,y) coordinate in, RGB (x,y) coordinate out. Simple.

To get the RGB data at some given coordinates, you must first grab an RGB frame using `NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame` to get an `INuiFrameTexture` instance. Call `LockRect` on this to get a `NUI_LOCKED_RECT`. The `pBits` property of this object is a pointer to the first pixel of the raw XRGB image. This image is stored row wise, in top-to-bottom left-to-right order, with each pixel being represented by 4 sequential bytes representing a padding byte then R, G and B follwing it.

The pixel at position `(100, 200)` is therefore at

```
lockedRect->pBits[ ((200 * width * 4) + (100 * 4) ];
```

and the byte representing the red channel should be at

```
lockedRect->pBits[ ((200 * width * 4) + (100 * 4) + 1 ];
```

This is a standard 32bit RGB image format, and the buffer can be freely passed to your image manipulation library of choice... GDI, WIC, OpenCV, IPL, whatever.

(caveat... I'm not totally certain I have the pixel byte ordering correct. I think it is XRGB, but it could be XBGR or BGRX, for example. Testing for which one is actually being returned should be trivial)

Comment: what I don't understand about `NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution`: this function will only return me the X/Y coordinate of the color frame for the corresponding depth frame. But I want to also get the color information. How do I get that? Do you happen to have an example?

Comment: @memyself Well, you can get the RGB values directly from the colour image, right? You can grab the colour frame using `NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame` on the RGB stream, and then use `pFrameTexture->LockRect` to grab the RGB buffer. It is stored as a normal 32 bit per pixel XRGB image

Comment: I understand how to grab the RGB buffer, but I don't know how to access the pixel value of each channel at position x, y.

Comment: @memyself instructions appended to my answer.